# Как переместить каретку ввода в TextBox на C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте уважаемые кодеры.

Заранее указываю что пишу программу для **Windows Forms** на **.NET 2.0 C#**
У меня есть **TextBox** в который я ввожу число (может быть как целое - **Integer**, так и с плавающей точкой - **Float**) и у меня есть метод который проверяет ввод на правильность. Так вот, когда я ввожу в свой **TextBox** точку (**.**), мой метод автоматически меняет ее на кому (**,**), при этом каретка ввода перемещается на начало поля ввода. Это очень не удобно. Мне нужно чтобы каретка оставалась на своем месте, то есть в конце, ну или как-то программно ее туда переставлять. Я перерыл много сайтов но то что мне нужно так и не нашел.

Если кто знает как это реализовать, пожалуйста помогите.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поставить каретку в конец строки:

```
textbox.SelectionStart = textbox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо Вам большое)